# Input arguments for tf::Vector3() tf::Quaternion()

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know the kind of input arguments passed both in the tf::Vector3() tf::Quaternion() as in the code below:

```
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.z, pose3D_LDD.pose.orientation.w));
```

Specifically, I want to know, are they absolute or relative? By the way, those all those lines reside in a callback function. For a more detail version of the code snippet of it, kindly refer to the code snippet [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/3832/changing-from-tftransform-to-tfstampedtransform).

I know that tf::Vector3() tf::Quaternion() refer to translation and rotation respectively but, should they be passed as absolute or relative in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12909/input-arguments-for-tf::vector3()-tf::quaternion()/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They should be passed in relative to the parent frame.

For example, you have base_link, located at (0, 0, 0) with a roll, pitch, and yaw of (0, 0, 0). Let's say that your sensor is located 1 meter in front of your robot, and it is inverted (upside down). Then, you would set the transform origin to (1, 0, 0) with RPY of (0, M_PI, 0).

```
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(1.0, 0, 0));
xform.setRotation(tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(0, M_PI, 0));
```

If the sensor were located behind the robot, it would be:

```
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(-1.0, 0, 0));
xform.setRotation(tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(0, M_PI, 0));
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-06**:
You can do tf::transformPose() to transform the pose from the world frame to the same frame as the cloud.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-06**:
pose3D_LDD represents absolute values for x, y and z.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-06**:
cont'd: should have been written as [should have been written as [xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(previous_pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x-pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x, previous_pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y-pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y, previous_pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z-pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z));]

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-06**:
I don't know what pose3D_LDD represents.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-06**:
For instance, xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D_LDD.pose.position.x, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.y, pose3D_LDD.pose.position.z));
]

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-06**:
If it is relative, that means, I've to pass in the value, like (previousValueOfX - ValueOfX) for each of them correspondingly. Am i right?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-06**:
With respect to the input values in my code snippet(that you once suggested that way), what was your assumption? relative or absolute?